# iPhone: Mask UIImageView of differing dimensions into square dimension

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a bunch of UIImageViews that are in different proportions.  Some of 100x101 some are 130x121.

How can I mask these to 80x80 and NOT stretch the images?  I basically just want to mask a square out of each one.  (kind of like the Apple's Photo thumbnail view does)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Set the image view's size to 80 x 80
2. set the image view's **contentMode** property to **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill**
3. Finally, to make round corners, use the following code, and import **QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h** at the beginning of your implementation file.

   ```
   CALayer * layer = [myImageView layer];
   [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
   [layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
   ```

Edited: Yes, by saying size I mean frame, the **W** and **H**:

[image]

Comment: You say set the image view's size.  do you mean frame?

Comment: `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` scales the image to the view's bounds--it only clips if the aspect ratio is different. Given @NicHubbard's description, I would think he needs `UIViewContentModeCenter`, which will cause the image to draw full-scale, and the layer will mask out all but the center 80x80 section.

Answer (score 0):

Set its content mode [UIViewContentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode), you may be looking for `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
.
.
.
```