# convert rectangular image to square image using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I am working on creating an image gallery which has thumbnails in different sizes. I want to convert these rectangle thumbnails to square size so that all of them could appear similar in size. I dont mind cropping it from extended portion but I am not sure how to do it. can anyone please help me?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789067/iphone-mask-uiimageview-of-differing-dimensions-into-square-dimension

Comment: That doesn't actually *create* a thumbnail, merely makes it look like one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the image in rect method passing in the image and the required bounds...

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([anImage CGImage], requiredBounds);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I have added this to a UIImage category (UIImage+Resize) in the following post, you can download the source code as well - [Categories example](http://locassa.com/index.php/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use an `UIImageView` to display your images (wich I am more than sure that you do) you can set it's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. This should 'crop' your image to the boundaries of your UIImageView. In case your image will go out of the boundaries of the `UIImageView` make sure `clipsToBounds` is also set to `YES`.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I agree. This is the 'easy' way out :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the next method. The input are the UIImage to scale and the size of the UIImageView's frame where the UIImage is. It works when the frame's height and width are equal.

**One important thing:** I keep the image's ratio. I don't expand the image to cover the full square. If you want to do it you have to change the 'drawInRect' line for `[self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];` and remove the if-else.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    CGFloat scaleRatio;

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {

        scaleRatio = image.size.height/image.size.width;

    }else{

        scaleRatio = image.size.width/image.size.height;
    }

    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, scaleTransform);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {

        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, (newSize.height/2)-(newSize.height*scaleRatio/2), newSize.width, newSize.height*scaleRatio)];

    }else{

        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake((newSize.width/2)-(newSize.width*scaleRatio/2), 0, newSize.width*scaleRatio, newSize.height)];
    }

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```